# Python: ogr2osm create osm file from WFS

Tags: python, openstreetmap, wfs, ogr2ogr

Does anyone know if `ogr2osm` can use WFS Layer as input source to create a osm file i could not find anything in the documentation expect that it should support all ogr file formats.

If so how can I do something like that (with `ogr2osm`)?

Comment: What format are you requesting from the WFS

Answer (score 1):

Do it in two steps

```
ogr2ogr -f 'ESRI Shapefile' -lco ENCODING=UTF-8 exploit_active_p.shp WFS:"http://geoservices.brgm.fr/odmgm" ms:EXPLOIT_ACTIVE_P
```

Then, convert the file "as usual" with `ogr2osm` e.g

```
ogr2osm exploit_active_p.shp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try our [Geoconverter](http://geoconverter.hsr.ch/) (without warranty) and save your WFS to GeoJSON or Spatialite (or GeoPackage in near future). With this local file you can feed ogr2osm.

Answer (score 0):

You should check first that your import is in compliance with the OSM Import rules, because as a friend who is an expert in OSM said "All [bulk] imports are a bad idea."

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Guidelines